# Problems When Shooting Multiple Enemies round about 4 times in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I have Multiple Enemies they have a float number for health round about `250.0f`. So when I shoot at one of them that number should decrease by 50 each time I shoot at the enemy. But here's my problem: The first enemy dies round about 4/5 shots to it, but when I start to shoot at the other (after the first enemy), it takes 1 shot and dies.

So here's the Bullet script for the players Bullet, called Bullet.cs:

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject BulletObject;
public GameObject GlobelObjectExplosion;
public GameObject GlobelBulletExplosion;
public float life = 3.0f;
private EnemyAI enemy;


private Transform bulletTransform;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {

        EnemyAI.currEnemyLife -= 50;
        Player.score += 50;

        //Creates an explosion on collision
        GameObject objBullet = Instantiate(GlobelBulletExplosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Destroy(objBullet, 2.0f);

        Debug.Log("ColliderWorking");

        if(EnemyAI.currEnemyLife <= 0.0f)
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

            //creates an explosion when enemy is destoryed
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(GlobelObjectExplosion, other.gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

            Destroy(obj, 2.0f);
            Player.score += 250;
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    life -= Time.deltaTime;

    transform.Translate(0, 0, Player.bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(life <= 0.0)
    {

        Destroy(gameObject);

    }

}
```

}

And heres the EnemyAI Script, called EnemyAI.cs:

```
public class EnemyAI: MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public int moveSpeed;
public int rotationSpeed;
public GameObject explosion;

public static float maxEnemyLife = 250.0f;
public static float currEnemyLife;
public static float maxEnemyBullets = 60.0f;
public static float currEnemyBullets;
public static float maxEnemyFuel = 1260.0f;
public static float currEnemyFuel;

private Transform myTranform;
public static Transform LocalTransform;

void Awake(){

    myTranform = transform;
    LocalTransform = myTranform;

}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    if(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player") != null){
        GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

        currEnemyFuel = maxEnemyFuel;
        currEnemyLife = maxEnemyLife;
        currEnemyBullets = maxEnemyBullets;

        target = go.transform;
    }



}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (currEnemyFuel > maxEnemyFuel)
    {
        currEnemyFuel = maxEnemyFuel;   
    }

        //Debug.DrawLine(target.position, myTranform.position, Color.cyan);
    if(currEnemyFuel <= 0.0)
    {
            currEnemyFuel = 0.0f;
            //myTranform.rotation = Vector3.zero;
            //myTranform.position = Vector3.zero;
        moveSpeed = 0;
    }
    else if (currEnemyFuel > 0.0)
    {
        //Look at target
        if(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player") != null){
            myTranform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTranform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTranform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            //Move towards Target
            myTranform.position += myTranform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            currEnemyFuel -= 0.2f;
        }

    }


}
```

}

I've tried to find if someone had the some problem or if theres a workaround, but I can't find a solution on here or google. So can someone tell me if im doing something wrong or is there a tutorial or something.

Comment: I'm no unity expert but my suspicion is that the `currEnemyLife` value is being reduced for all enemies on screen.  Each `Enemy` object needs to contain its own specific `currEnemyLife` value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The properties in `Enemy` are all `static`, which means there is only one of each of them shared between the whole application. So the next enemy, that dies straight away, will be using the life of the previous one, which is already dead.

Remove the `static` modifier from the `currEnemyLife`, `currEnemyBullets` and `currEnemyFuel` properties.

Then you'll need to change the way you modify these values in `Bullet`, as you can no longer access them directly through `EnemyAI`. I don't know much about Unity3D but after doing a little reading I think you'd need to do something like this:

```
var enemy = otherObject.GetComponent<EnemyClass>();
enemy.currEnemyLife -= 50f;
// etc...
```

Comment: Your answer is good. I just don't like to use that way to get object of the collision cause I have problem with that kind of code in past in a game I was making. But it can work for him.